# PHP: Cannot get regex pattern to repeat

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have an input string that looks something like this:

```
$txt = '!1 aaa !2 bb bb !5 cc cc cc !4 dd';
```

In other words, I have a number of fields, each starting with an exclamation mark and a digit.

It want to turn this into something like this:

```
<div class="x1">aaa</div>
<div class="x2">bb bb</div>
<div class="x5">cc cc cc</div>
<div class="x4">dd</div>
```

where the `div` class derives from the digit following the exclamation mark in the input string.

I've tried this PHP command:

```
preg_replace("/!([0-9]) (.*) !/U", "<div class=\"x\\1\">\\2</div>\n!", $txt)
```

But that produces this output:

```
<div class="x1">aaa</div>
!2 bb bb <div class="x5">cc cc cc</div>
!4 dd
```

It's obvious that the last field (`!4 dd`) is not matched, since it doesn't have a final !. And I assume that the second field (`!2 bb bb`) is not matched because its initial ! actually comes from the replacement of the first string.

So, I guess I know why it isn't working, but I can't work out how to do this correctly.

Comment: You need `/!([0-9])\s*(.*?)\s*(?=!\d|$)/` or `/!(\d+)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=!\d|$)/s`

Comment: Note that if your fields don't contain exclamation mark `!` (except at the start) and aren't empty, you can use this simple pattern: [`!(\d+) ([^!]*[^! ])`](https://regex101.com/r/vaXoId/1).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```php
echo preg_replace('~!(\d+)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=!\d|$)~s', "<div class=\"x\$1\">\$2</div>\n", $txt);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2jyEFF/1) and the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/uFr20). *Details*:

- `!` - a `!` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?=!\d|$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a `!` + digit or end of string.

Comment: That's perfect, Wiktor! Thank you.